# Having problems using random.sample on a dictionary

Tags: python, random

I'm making a quiz for a teacher of mine to teach her students. The quiz is going to have 50+ questions at the end. I found about random.sample and implemented it in my code but it seems to have not effect. Even though I'm using random.sample sometimes the question repeat themselves after just being called. I'm pretty new to Python and I'm dumbfounded by this.

```
import random
# Stores Question, choices and answers 
questions = {
        'What should you do when links appear to be broken when using the Check Links Site wide command?':  # Q 1
         [' A) Test the link in a browser \n B) Test the link in live view \n C) Check the File path \n D) View Source Code', 'A'],

        'Which 3 combinations of factors encompass usability?':  # Q 2
        [' A) Amount of ads,Load time,Window Size \n B) Load Time,Ease of navigation,Efficiency of use \n C) Server download time, \n D) proper Navigation', 'B'],

        'Which line of html code describes a link to an absolute url using the <A> tag and href attribute?':  # Q 3
        [' A) <A herd = "http://www.acmetoon.org">Acme Toons!</a>, \n B) Herf = "http://www.acmetoon.org">Acme Toons!</a>,'
            '\n C) <A herf = "http://www.acmetoon.org">Acme Toons!</a> \n D) <A herf > = "http://www.acmetoon.org">Acme Toons!</a>', 'A']


        }


print('Dreamweaver Practice test V 1.0')


def pick_question():
        wrong_answers = 0
        while True:
            print()
            # Uses sample to get an item off the dict
            sample_question = random.sample(list(questions.keys()), 3) 
            # Converts the list to a single word ['hello'] -> hello 
            # So no errors complaining about it being it list popup
            new = sample_question[0]
            # Print question and choices 
            print(new)
            print(questions[new][0])
            print()
            user_answer = input('Enter Answer: ')
            print()
            # If the user choice matches the answer
            if user_answer == questions[new][1]:
                print('Correct')
                print()
                print('----Next Question----')
                print()
            elif wrong_answers == 10:
                print('Game Over')
                break
            else:
                print('Wrong')
                print('Correct letter was ' + questions[new][1])
                wrong_answers += 1
                print('Amount wrong ' + str(wrong_answers) + '/10')
                print()
                print('----Next Question----')
                print()


pick_question()
```

Comment: Try using random.choice

Comment: Each time you go round the `while True:` loop, you're using random sample to pick 3 random questions. You then ask the first question of those 3. The next time you want to ask a question, you take a new sample of 3 and use the first. Is the intention to ask 3 questions and then stop?

Comment: @SimeonAleksov Already tried using random.choice.  That was my first thought. That's why I switched to random.sample.

Comment: @TomDalton As long as the user get's it correct it can keep on going.  Right now it's 3 questions but once I fix this bug I'm going to add over 50.  I just don't want those question to repeat.  1 1 2 3 instead 1 3 2 or 2 3 1 - 2 1 3 Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomize your list of questions with `random.shuffle` first then just iterate as normal:

```
...
def quick_questions():
    wrong_answers = 0
    question_keys = list(questions.keys())
    random.shuffle(question_keys) # questions is now in a random order
    for question_key in question_keys:
        new = questions[question_key]
        print()
        # Print question and choices 
        print(new)
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the nobie question but where do I implement this into my code to test it out?

Comment: I tired the shuffle and I got an error.                                                           shuffle x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
KeyError: 2

Comment: @nk001 whoops, sorry. didn't realize that `questions` was a `dict`. i've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  After hours of searching I found the answer I was looking for by  mistake while trying to mix your code and mine together.  :D

Answer (score 0):

The following may help you understand what your code is really doing, than why it isn't behaving as expected:

```
import random
# Stores Question, choices and answers 
questions = {'key1': ['text1','ans1'], 'key2': ['text2','ans2'], 'key3':['text3','ans3']}

for i in range (0,10):
    sample_question = random.sample(list(questions.keys()), 3)
    print(sample_question)
```

A sample output of which may yield:

```
['key2', 'key3', 'key1']
['key3', 'key1', 'key2']
['key3', 'key1', 'key2']
['key3', 'key1', 'key2']
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
['key3', 'key2', 'key1']
['key1', 'key3', 'key2']
['key3', 'key2', 'key1']
['key1', 'key3', 'key2']
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
['key3', 'key1', 'key2']
```

In other words, you are effectively picking a question at random, but not removing the question from your question list. That's why you have repetition. It's like shuffling a deck of card, pointing of one them, then shuffling it again and pointing one of them again - without even removing anything from the deck.

(I know this doesn't really provide an "answer", but you seemed to want to understand why your code wasn't behaving.Jack's answer is pretty good)